# How to parse out a column in sql with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a sql server table named [City_St_Zip] that contains records that look like this

> Dallas, TX 12345

What I would like to do is separate the column into three different columns (i.e. City, State and Zip)
like this:

> Dallas
>
> > TX
> >
> > > 12345

I am not sure how to go about this in SQL

I have tried the following

```
DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(100),
DECLARE @T NVARCHAR(100),
SELECT
   @X = [City_St_Zip],
   @T = [NewDivision]
FROM
   dbo.Invoice
      CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@X, ',');
```

This yielded 0 results so I am pretty sure I did that incorrectly

Any suggestions?  I am using SQL Server 2019

EDIT:
I also tried this which is closer to what I want

```
SELECT 
   value
FROM
  dbo.Invoice
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([City_St_Zip], ',');
```

That gives me a result set of:

> Dallas
>
> > TX 12345

So I guess this is convoluted and needs both a comma and a space delimiter.  Would I just put the value through another STRING_SPLIT?

Comment: You're passing a comma to `STRING_SPLIT` as the delimiter, and yet in your example, you seem to want to split by a space.  Also, why not pass `[City_St_Zip]` to the function instead of `@X`?  Also, you should consider how to handle cities that have more than one word in the name if you indeed want to split by a space.

Comment: Your select columns do not include the `value` output from `string_split` which is going to be `null` in this case because you're trying to split `@x` instead of your `City_St_Zip` column. See the String_Split docs, [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Comment: @devlincarnate I tried what you suggested please see the updated question

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that was an oops on my part thank you for pointing that out I fixed it

Comment: String split is wrong. Fort Worth, TX 00000 will break

Comment: @user1713450 I agree after further testing.  String split will not work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `STRING_SPLIT` then this will work without variables.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table dbo.Invoice
> (
>   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   [City_St_Zip] nvarchar(100)
> );
>
> insert into dbo.Invoice 
> ([City_St_Zip]) values
> ('Dallas, TX 12345'),
> ('Fort Worth, TX 12345')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT inv.*, a.*
> FROM dbo.Invoice inv
> OUTER APPLY 
> (
>    SELECT
>    [1] AS [City], 
>    LTRIM(LEFT([2], 3)) AS [State],
>    TRIM(SUBSTRING([2],4,LEN([2]))) AS [Zip]
>    FROM
>    ( SELECT spl.value
>      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rn
>      FROM STRING_SPLIT(inv.[City_St_Zip],',') spl
>    ) s
>    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rn IN ([1],[2])) p
> ) a;
> ```

**Result:**

> ```
> id | City_St_Zip          | City       | State | Zip  
> -: | :------------------- | :--------- | :---- | :----
>  1 | Dallas, TX 12345     | Dallas     | TX    | 12345
>  2 | Fort Worth, TX 12345 | Fort Worth | TX    | 12345
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6c8a1c6917833ee8f0b77926bc91f2d8)*

**Extra:**

Using the XML type, this SQL will also work in an earlier version like Sql Server 2012.

```
SELECT inv.*
, a.City
, RTRIM(LEFT(a.StateZip, CHARINDEX(' ',a.StateZip))) AS State
, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.StateZip, CHARINDEX(' ',a.StateZip),LEN(a.StateZip))) AS Zip
FROM dbo.Invoice inv
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT X.x AS CityStateZipXml
  , X.x.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS City
  , LTRIM(X.x.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')) AS StateZip
  FROM (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<x>', REPLACE(inv.[City_St_Zip],',','</x><x>'),'</x>') AS XML)
  ) AS X(x)
) a;
```

Comment: This is very close but as mentioned in the comments on my question Fort Worth, TX 12345 comes out like Fort is the City, Worth is the state and TX is the zip code.  How would I accommodate for the space in city names

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!  I had no idea the amount of work just to parse that out.

Comment: It used to be worse. There's also alternatives by using the XML type.  But I would cheer if MS would someday include something like the [MySql SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has poor string processing support.  And, `string_split()` is not guaranteed to keep the values in order.  And string searches are dangerous -- think New York, New York.

So, a brute force method:

```
select left(col, charindex(',', col) - 1) as city,
       substring(col, charindex(',', col) + 2, 2) as state,
       right(col, 5) as zipcode
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fea2635f6b49926eec6cc3a86f31da6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Would this apply when getting the original value from a table column.  For example dbo.Invoice.[City_St_Zip]?  Other than that it works perfectly

Comment: @MaxG . . . Yes.  The db<>fiddle essentially shows that (the column is named `col`).

Answer (score 0):

*** Updated as per SQL Server***

```
create table ctry
( 
  city_st_zip nvarchar(100)
);

insert into ctry values('Dallas, TX 12345');
```

--SQL USED--

```
SELECT
LEFT([city_st_zip], CHARINDEX(',', [city_st_zip]) - 1) AS [City],
SUBSTRING([city_st_zip], CHARINDEX(',', [city_st_zip]) + 2, 2) as [State],
RIGHT([city_st_zip], CHARINDEX(' ', [city_st_zip]) - 2) AS [Zip]
FROM ctry;
```

--Result--

```
City    State   Zip
Dallas  TX  12345
```